# how to parse a long double from scientific notation

Tags: c, pow, atoi, long-double

I have a text file with numbers in **scientific notation** stored as a **string** of characters, some of which have up to `20` digits. For example, `2.3456789e-015`. I need to convert this into a long double in order to perform some mathematical operations on it.

How can I accomplish this?

```
long double number = 2.3456789e-015;
```

I know I can declare a **long double** like so, but the trouble comes when I have the number as a string and need to specify the base as well as the exponent separately. The `pow()` function only works on **doubles** and `cpowl()` has no way to be formatted in `printf`. It is important that I keep the precision!!

Comment: [`strtold`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) would seem a pretty good candidate for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert string to long double, use `[stold][1]`

If you want to `printf` long double, use `%Lf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `double atof(const char*)`.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf(str, "%lf", &number)` understands any formats. scanf and sscanf allow checking the result of conversion:

```cpp
    if( sscanf(str, "%lf", &number) )
    {
        printf("number = %le\n", number);
    }
```